# How to add new facebook page plugin to a HTML website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

```js
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=118035745195680";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

```html
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" data-height="300" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook">Facebook</a></blockquote></div></div>
```

I added this already but it is not appering on my website.

Comment: you will have to use FB api to access any information.

Comment: Check the browser console for errors. Or link us to an example.

Comment: @bharathv Thanks it works

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks It works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a sample application of using FB api in ur website.
I think this would be helpful.
https://github.com/bandhavya/SampleFBApplication/